# Mass update About Me / OpenID information for all associated accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

When you associate an account on a stackexchange site you haven't visited before your personal information is automatically added.

What I would like is a method to replicate a change to all sites at a later point in time.

Also if possible I would like to be able to mass-change my openid providers.

Or as an alternative instead of replicate the data, perhaps there could be a single location where you could update everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have nothing for you regarding OpenID, but you can already mass-replicate personal info changes:

[image: screenshot of accounts tab]

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Replicating the profile information was primarily what I wanted.  I never noticed that button before.

Comment: That is **not** red.

Comment: @tvanfosson, what?